# What does data.strip() with XML mean in Python?

Tags: python, xml, string

I do not understand the end of this statement:

```
print node.getElementsByTagName(`author')[0].childNodes[0].data.strip()
```

What does `data.strip()` do in this statement?

Comment: There's documentation for such questions.

Comment: Same thing it does on every other string.

Comment: @Kiril: He assumes that this is an XML method. If he searches through the XML-related documentation, he could spend a long time with no success, because he would be searching in the wrong place.

Comment: Assuming and guessing is one thing...looking the type of the object and checking its API is a different thing...this is programming by guessing.

Comment: @Sentinel: Sounds like a lot of people I know.

Answer (score 6):

It removes extra whitespace from the beginning and end of the string. This is not XML-specific, but is a general string method in Python [which you can find in the documentation here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Answer (score 2):

Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed (defaulting to removing whitespace characters)

http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-string.html